# React doesn't respond to dispatched change event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

I'm handling `onPaste`, parsing the data, then I need to trigger any existing `onChange` handlers.

```
const event = new Event("change", { bubbles: true});
e.target.dispatchEvent(event);
```

It works fine on native input elements, but doesn't seem to work on React components. Dispatching the `change` has no effect when used on the component

Here's a code sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-paste-change-1tr5k

`e.preventDefault` is necessary because the contents need to be replaced after parsing.

Seems to be related to event bubbling and/or how React synthetic events behave but I can't pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround for now, used `input` event instead of `change`.

```
const ev2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true})
e.target.dispatchEvent(ev2)
```

Note that the "custom" component in the above example is simply a wrapped `<input>`:

```
const CustomInput = (props) => <input onChange={props.onChange} />
```

Still stumped why the change event handler doesn't fire.